# How do I enforce changes in an oh-my-zsh function?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to look into [this issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7653), and figured out I would have to debug [this function](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/6d143d42ea2e16610855e5b1e912b2962d44d9ab/lib/git.zsh#L33-L59), but I cannot see any effect when changing or even removing that function, and that even after opening a new terminal window! How come? How can a function still be defined if its source no longer exists? Is there some kind of cache I need to clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there is no magic, it's just that I have zplug installed and it has [a copy](https://github.com/zplug/zplug/blob/master/base/utils/theme.zsh#L1) of that function I was attempting to change…